# Bulk Adding To Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

What I am looking for is to be able to add to an object, but not to do something like messageStrings.x = 1 for each one.

For example, in one file we may have something like:

```
var messageStrings = {
     Edit: "Edit",
     Cancel: "Cancel"
}
```

and another file, want to add more to the object:

```
var messageStrings = {
    Update: "Update",
    Save: "Save"
}
```

What is the best way of doing a bulk add to an existing object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many libraries provide an "extend" function, which lets you do something like this:

```
var obj = extend({ "default": "something"}, { "more": "stuff", "even": "more" });
```

which would give you an object with properties "default", "more", and "even."

What the function looks like is this:

```
function extend() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

  var target = args[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
    for (var k in args[i]) {
      target[k] = args[i][k];
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

Some implementations might have slightly varying semantics, such as whether to always return a result that's a freshly-minted object, or instead to always modify the first parameter like that one does.

Note also that that's a *shallow copy* — to make a *complete* "deep" copy, you'd need more code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in typescript:

```
var messageStrings = {
 Edit: "Edit",
 Cancel: "Cancel"
}
var messageString2 = {
 Update: "Update",
 Save: "Save"
}
let obj = {...messageStrings, ...messageString2}
```

it will give you:

```
{Edit: "Edit", Cancel: "Cancel", Update: "Update", Save: "Save"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge new values into the existing object. 
jQuery has [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method for this.

If jQuery is not an option, you can write up a simple recursive contraption (probably checking `hasOwnProperty` just in case some library littered `Object.prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can extend an object in this way:

> $.extend(objectA, objectB);

In this way you will get an object containing both A and B properties.

Otherwise you can use a simple **for in** loop like:

```
for (var x in obj2) {
  obj1[x] = obj2[x];
}
```

This is of course a mere example, you should do some check to avoid data overwriting